# Error de shape al predecir nuevos datos con SVM

Tags: python, machine-learning, text

No encuentro el modo de predecir nuevos datos con un modelo de SVM, al intentar ingresar por ejemplo una sola frase me marca error de shape, que no es del mismo tamaño que el dataset de entrenamiento

> X.shape[1] = 8 should be equal to 16004, the number of features at training time

Por lo que entiendo mi frase nueva a predecir no cuenta con el largo de palabras (8) que el máximo del largo de palabras que el dataset de entrenamiento (16004) o algo similar, por lo cual mi duda es como puedo predecir nuevos datos? dejo mi código:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
count_vect = CountVectorizer()

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()

rbf = svm.SVC(kernel='rbf', gamma=1, C=10, decision_function_shape='ovo').fit(X_train, y_train)
rbf_pred = rbf.predict(X_test)

sentence = ['El jueves visitare a mi familia que quiero mucho']
sv = count_vect.fit_transform(sentence)
st = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(sv)

rbf_pred = rbf.predict(st) #Error
```